# how to send mask card number instead of complete card number to Sabre AirTicketLLSRQ api?

Tags: payment, credit-card, sabre

We are handling payment at our side so we dont want sabre to do this for us. And so we just need to inform sabre about payment is done and it should reflect in to final ticket. But as per there api they want whole card number so is there any provision or any other method by which we can pass mask card number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things to comment:

1. The most important thing to highlight here is that if you put the credit card on the AirTicket call, it will be charged.
2. There is no way to send a masked credit card, you either send one to be charged or not send it.
3. If you don't want to send the credit card, which seems to be a sensible thing to do since you are handling the payment, then in the AirTicket call you should use CASH for payment.